# JQuery Carousel Scroll, fadeout, fadein

Tags: jquery, html, css, carousel

Just learning Jquery so I apologize in advance if this question seems basic. I've got the following Jquery code that controls a Carousel.

```
$('#carousel_ul:not(:animated)').animate({'left' : left_indent, opacity:0},600,function(){
            /* when the animation finishes use the if statement again, and  make an illusion
            of infinity by changing place of last or first item*/
            if(where == 'left'){
                //...and if it slided to left we put the last item before  the first item
                $('#carousel_ul li:first').before($('#carousel_ul  li:last'));
            }else{
                //...and if it slided to right we put the first item after the last item
                $('#carousel_ul li:last').after($('#carousel_ul li:first'));
            }

            //...and then just get back the default left indent
            $('#carousel_ul').css({'left' : '-300px'});
            $('#carousel_ul').delay(100).animate({opacity:1}, 400);
        });
```

It's working great, other than the fact it's not quite accomplishing the effect I'm going for. So I want the fadeout and fadein to occur while the carousel is scrolling. Right now it scrolls and the fadeout happens while it's scrolling, but then it fades back in after the scroll has completed. Anyone have some suggestions. Can I chain the fadeOut() fadeIn() somehow with the animate? When I try that say for example:

```
$('#carousel_ul:not(:animated)')fadeOut().fadeIn().animate({opacity:0}
```

It fades out, then fades in, then animates. I'm sure I'm overlooking something obvious here... Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle of that?

Comment: Sure. I roughed together a demo with placeholder images - the relevant code to this in the JQuery starts at the //FUNCTIONS BELOW
Please disregard the bad images and spacing. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epVObx  I want the fade In to happen while it's still scrolling. So fadeout while scrolling then fadein next product.

Comment: This is not that obvious, unless you will find a way to add `active` class to the current item (`li` tag).

Comment: I know it's surprisingly difficult - is there a way to fadeOut and fadeIn simultaneously to the scroll? Perhaps in a separate function from the animate function?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VvQwzW - is this what are you looking for?

Comment: Yes very close. Problem is when I preview in chrome it isn't working, and when I apply the code to my actual project it isn't working anywhere. Are you doing something in the HTML that I'm overlooking? Do you think this could be resolved with a gradient mask? (that's how I would of done in Flash)

Comment: I added CSS and JS at the bottom. I used CSS Animations. One problem - if you click very fast on the arrow animation does not work (because of the delay in jQuery)